# VBa and Excel - Filter a table with a variant

Tags: excel, vba, filter, variant

I'm trying to Filter a table with more than one parameter stored in a variant (SelectedPiers).
I've tried with this two codes:

```
  For Each Pier In SelectedPiers
        .Range("A3:J" & FileLastRow).AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=Pier
  Next
```

```
.Range("A3:L" & FileLastRow).AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=SelectedPiers
```

The two of them just filter the table only by the last value. The variant is filled with strings.

Comment: Now `SelectedPiers` does  look? Please, try the second variant, but add the next parameter, too: `Operator:=xlFilterValues`.

Comment: Operator:=xlFilterValues did the trick ! Thank you very much !

Comment: Glad I could help! I asked about how the array looks in order to see if you tried something like "<>string". In such a case, only two conditions are admitted...